# Swagger array of objects

Tags: arrays, object, swagger

I am having some issues with swagger: I have an array of objects (address) described in this way in the .yaml file:

```
Address:
  properties:
    street:
      type: string
    city:
      type: string
    state:
      type: string
    country:
      type: string
```

and this is the other yaml file with the definitions of the API (address is a params):

```
 - name: addresses
   in: formData
   description: List of adresses of the user. The first one is the default one.
   type: array
   items:
     $ref: '#/definitions/Address'
```

And this is the text I put in the swagger UI:

```
[
  {
    "street": "Bond street",
    "city": "Torino",
    "state": "Italy",
    "country": "Italy"
  }
]
```

but in node.js, if I print what I receive:

> {"addresses":["[","  {","    \"street\": \"Bond street\","," 
>   \"city\": \"Torino\",","    \"state\": \"Italy\",","    \"country\":
>   \"Italy\"","  }","]"]}

And I get a parsing error... There are some extra [ and ". It seems that swagger parse it as string (?)

Comment: Is there any significance in your usage of `the .yaml file` (with dot) and `the other yaml file` (without dot)?

Comment: Please post your complete .yaml files. Are they in the same folder? What code do you use to print the data on your Node.js side?

Comment: No, the yaml files are not in the same folders, but I don't think this is the problem since the descriptions in swagger ui work.
To print the data I use JSON.stringify

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To send JSON data, you need to use use an `in: body` parameter (not `in: formData`) and specify that the operation consumes `application/json`. `formData` parameters are used for operations that consume `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

```
paths:
  /something:
     post:
       consumes:
         - application/json
       parameters:
         - in: body
           name: addresses
           required: true
           schema:
             type: array
             items:
               $ref: "#/definitions/Address"  # if "Address" is in the same file
               # or
               # $ref: "anotherfile.yaml#/definitions/Address"  # if "Address" is in another file
```

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions. But something is not working anyway. I changed the `in:body` but still

Comment: Define "is not working". Does Swagger UI render this incorrectly? Does you backend receive incorrect data? The more details the better.

Comment: yes, sorry for the short answer yesterday. Still receiving wrong data in my BE.

Comment: Hello, In the end I was able to fix it. I didn't notice the change in schema. Thank you.