# How to write the Array In Swagger?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

**API Documentation in Swagger**

```
- name: orderNo
              in: query
              description: Number of the order
              required: false
              schema:
                type: integer
                format: int32
            - name: orderName
              in: query
              description: Name of the order
              required: false
              schema:
                type: string
```

**JSON**

```
"orderNo": 6362131469,
  "orderName": "HuntPrivateOrder",
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "name": "Hunt T-Shirt",
      "id": 1,
      "sku": 11456873613,
      "quantity": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Hunt Tomato",
      "id": 1,
      "sku": 11456873677,
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ],
```

How do I convert my array in my JSON File to the proper Swagger Format? I only know how to convert the non-array but not the actual array. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array of objects as an input parameter in swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627929/array-of-objects-as-an-input-parameter-in-swagger) and [Swagger array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43711744/113116).

Comment: This is 2.0, I need the OpenAPI 3.0 example for Arrays